# Why dialog doesn't support emacs shell on Debian?

Tags: shell, terminal, emacs

[Dialog](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/dialog) is a utility that provides dialog boxes from shell scripts, you may have seen them in aptitude during upgrades. When i use Emacs shell (`M-x shell`) and type `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`, i get the following error several times:

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
```

Why doesn't Dialog work with Emacs shell? And should i use some substitute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dialog uses [`ncurses`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which doesn't work in Emacs' `shell-mode`, and according to [SO: *"What would be a good alternative to ncurses that will work under emacs shell?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792073/993018), there's no suitable alternative to `ncurses` that would work in `emacs-shell`, **but** it hints to *full terminal capabilities* of other Emacs' modes (which unfortunately I know nothing about), maybe [Multi Term](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm)?

Comment: I tried to use `whiptail`, which uses `libnewt` instead of `ncurses`, and it said `Your terminal lacks the ability to clear the screen or position the cursor.` And i don't think multiterm supports ncurses.

Comment: There's also [Ansi Term](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm) and [EShell](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryEshell), maybe some combination of all these works  (I don't know which, sorry). Apparently Ansi Term can run `mutt` but I couldn't find out if that's linked against `ncurses` or `slang`.

Comment: Whether it's linked against `ncurses`, `slang`, or just sending out raw terminal directives (the horror), for a full-screen application to run on a terminal, that **terminal** must understand terminal directives (i.e. it's up to the terminal, not the library), and the OS must have an appropriate termcap/terminfo entry for it. By definition, a dumb terminal is one that doesn't grok terminal directives. Without them, you're limited to outputting characters (including ASCII control chars). No cursor repositioning, character attributes, clearing the screen etc. It's basically an ASR-33.

Comment: With a sufficiently new Emacs, `M-x term` *does* work with a graphical debconf, but you may need to pull in additional dependencies.  Tangentially, see also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs24/+bug/1285864 which suggests installing `ncurses-term`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, emacs has more than one shell.  There's a *dumb* shell which doesn't support full-screen terminal applications, and there is the "Ansi Term", which *does*.  You could even run emacs inside that shell (though running commands inside the window might be more complicated than using emacs in its usual manner).

For example, here is a screenshot of `dialog` running in a GUI emacs:

[image: screenshot of dialog in ansi-term / GUI]

and `dialog` running in emacs running in xterm:

[image: screenshot of dialog in ansi-term / xterm]

Keep in mind that *Ansi Term* is designed for a specific terminal description, [`eterm-color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-eterm-color) — which is *not* in the Debian [`ncurses-base`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ncurses-base) package: you would need [`ncurses-term`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ncurses-term).  Similar caveats apply to any system which defers the complete terminal database to a separate package.

Further reading:

- [AnsiTerm](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm) (Emacs wiki)
- [AnsiTermHints](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints) (Emacs wiki)
- [Emacs: Run Shell in Emacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_unix.html) (By Xah Lee)

As for the `debconf` message, google is your friend.  Here are some reasonably comprehensive answers:

- [Unable to initialize frontend: dialog when using ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506158/unable-to-initialize-frontend-dialog-when-using-ssh) (AskUbuntu)

Answer (score 1):

That is a normal message when executing unattended remote commands.  Just put this into top of your unattended script :

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

this will tell scripts you are executing an unattended script so they will know to just do default behaviour ... similar yet more generally applicable to adding the -y flag to some cli input parms