# M-x ansi-term colors in Emacs 24.x

Tags: shell, emacs, ls, colors, ansi-term

I have noticed that some colors in `LS_COLORS` don't work when running a shell inside `M-x-ansi-term` in Emacs.

For exmaple;

```
di 00 94
```

is supposed to turn on bold on light blue on directories on `LS_COLORS` (see a list of the codes [here](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors)), but `ansi-term` in Emacs does not show it in color. In fact, only the simple colors listed on that website seem to work under `ansi-term` in Emacs, while they work perfectly well on my regular gnome terminal.

Is there a way to get `ansi-term` to recognize the so called **extra** colors? Where/how can I look up the colors supported by `ansi-term` in Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

How about this command?

```
M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on
```

Answer (score 0):

`ansi-term` supports the 8 ANSI colors, using [`TERM=eterm-color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-eterm-color).  That gives you basic colors, e.g., as shown in *[Why dialog doesn't support emacs shell on Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34497/why-dialog-doesnt-support-emacs-shell-on-debian/295228#295228)* (sic).

That **`94`** is not one of the 8 ANSI colors.  It comes (originally) from aixterm, but was widely used because it was implemented in xterm in the late 1990s, as seen in ncurses terminal database entry [`xterm-16color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t1997052421_10_57).  dircolors, of course does not use the terminal database...

According to the Emacs wiki on [AnsiColor](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiColor), there is an alternative `xterm-colors.el` which can support more colors.

According to *that* page ([atomontage/xterm-color](https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color)), it can support xterm 256-colors.  Reading the script, I can see some omissions with respect to xterm, but colors should work.